# Custom WPF control for showing a Graph and highlighting Points of Interest

Tags: c#, wpf, custom-controls

Question for you all, I've been charged with developing an application to view data about a testing cycle we do for environmental screening, products are placed in an environmental control, freezing and heating the product while a variety of self-tests are run. My manager would like to see a graph of temperature over time as an x/y graph, but he'd also like to have an indicator for where the test is currently at that has a small box, giving additional info, (test status, current test, running time etc.)

So what I'm thinking is I need to make a custom control that is capable of displaying this scatter graph and can also contain another content control for my additional info box, what base control should I use as a foundation, what should I look at for drawing my graph, and how can I do my layout for this? I'm assuming the use of a canvas control is my best bet for layout, and DrawingGroups with PathFigures for the graph... anyone capable of giving me more guidance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[VisiFire](http://visifire.com/) maybe it's your choice.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you should check out Sacha Barber's [WPF Graph Control](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFTickerGraph.aspx). This may be a good starting point

Comment: I actually did look at that, but it seemed to be far too restrictive of a design for me, but maybe i'm just not thinking far enough past the surface.